# Import xml file to word document template using vbscript

Tags: xml, asp-classic, vbscript, ms-word

I'm hoping someone is able to help me with what I am trying to do, I have looked around the internet but haven't found anything that does exactly what I want.

What I am trying to do is create a Word Document using data from a SQL Server 2000 DB. At the minute I have created the Word Document, saved it as a webpage and then copied the generated code to an asp page and inserted the data from the DB. When visited the webpage then opens a word document for the user to print etc.

This works fine however the saved word document loses a lot of the formatting and doesn't look as intended when it is opened.

I was wondering if there was some way that I could create a word document and then insert xml data into the word document all using vbscript? Similar to a mail merge but using xml as the source and doing it through vbscript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Word supports saving documents in an *.xml format, so you could either do an XSL transform of your data to this schema or you could load a Word XML template into an XML library such as `MSXML2` and insert your data using the DOM functions. You could then write the resulting XML to the browser and if you set the content type header to something like `application/vnd.ms-word` the browser may download the document and automatically load it into a new Word instance on the client side.

I have done a very similar thing using Excel and Excel's XML Spreadsheet formats.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Word's custom xml data binding.  You inject your xml data into an xml part, and bind content controls in the document to it, via XPath.  Word will update the contents of the document dynamically to match the data in the xml part.